# Game Hangman code understanding (Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner, 3rd Edition,Chapter 5)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code that I found in my book for game `Hangman`:

```
HANGMAN=("""
------
|    |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|
|
|
|
|
|
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|   -+-
|
|  
|  
|  
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-
|  
|  
|  
|  
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
 |    |
 |    O
 |  /-+-/
 |  
 |  
 |  
 |  
 |  
 ----------
 """,
 """
 ------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|  
|  
|  
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|    |
|   |
|   |
|  
----------
""",
"""
------
|    |
|    O
|  /-+-/
|    |
|    |
|   | |
|   | |
|  
----------
""")

MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN) - 1
WORDS = ("OVERUSED", "CLAM", "GUAM", "TAFFETA", "PYTHON", "HARDWICKE", "BRADLEY", "SHEFFIELD")

# initialize variables
word = random.choice(WORDS)   # the word to be guessed
so_far = "-" * len(word)      # one dash for each letter in word to be guessed
wrong = 0                     # number of wrong guesses player has made
used = []                     # letters already guessed


print("Welcome to Hangman.  Good luck!")

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've used the following letters:\n", used)
    print("\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far)

print("\nOnly use one letter values, more than one letter at a time does not work at this time")
guess = input("\nEnter your guess: ")
guess = guess.upper()

while guess in used:
    print("You've already guessed the letter", guess)
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")
    guess = guess.upper()

used.append(guess)

if guess in word:
    print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

    # create a new so_far to include guess
    new = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess
        else:
            new += so_far[i]              
    so_far = new

else:
    print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
    wrong += 1

if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've been hanged!")
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it!")

print("\nThe word was", word)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

And I do not understand this part of code:

```
if guess in word:
    print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

    # create a new so_far to include guess
    new = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess
        else:
            new += so_far[i]              
    so_far = new

else:
    print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
    wrong += 1
```

This part of code have to make a new variable sofar which will show a targeted word with a guessed letters on the right position

```
# create a new so_far to include guess
    new = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new += guess
        else:
            new += so_far[i]              
    so_far = new
```

And I completely don't understand this last part
Help please!

Comment: there is a problem with the indentation of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new = ""                   #creates an empty string named new
for i in range(len(word)): #loop x times,x is word size,e.g. len("PYTHON") is 6
    if guess == word[i]:   
        new += guess       #adds the guess character to new string
    else:
        new += so_far[i]   #adds the existing character from so_far string(on first loop is '_')          
so_far = new
```

Example:
word = PYTHON, guess = 'T' ,so_far is _ _ _ _ _ _

after for loop

so_far is _ _ T _ _ _

Comment: I'd suggest making your answer more easily readable by adding some context. You could do this either by providing comments within a code block, or by formatting it as a discussion around the code you are commenting on.

Comment: Now I understand but Paschalis Siskos you have a fault in your  comment:   new += so_far[i]   #adds the '_' or letter which is already guessed to new string

Comment: Yes indeed,i was focused on the first loop.